# Which backend service(database) available for third party apps?

Tags: spotify

I am developing third party app.
For that, I want to store user related data.
So, I want to know that which backend service(database) is available for use?
and what is the storage space limit for it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotify doesn't provide any back-end services for you to use. However, you may also use any service you wish, or write your own.